# When do uniformly most powerful (UMP) tests fail to exist and how to prove it?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

Is there a simple example for a pair of hypotheses for which a uniformly most powerful (UMP) test does not exist? How does one go about proving this? Is it true that for tests with double-sided hypotheses, a UMP test does not exist? Is it true that for multivariate parameters, a UMP tests does not exist?

Comment: split this into multiple questions

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188752/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/181255/119261