# When does a UMP test fail to exist?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I have a sample $X=(X_1, ...,X_n)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2$ known. The hypotheses are  $H_0: \mu=\mu_0, H_1:\mu \neq \mu_0$. 
I know that in such a case an UMP test does not exist and so that I should proceed using a LR test, in order to find the rejection rule.

My professor also told me that for a sample distribution that belongs to the Exponential Family in the case of simple vs bilateral hypotheses an UMP test does not exist.

Thus, my question is theoretic: why does an UMP test does not exist in such cases? Which are the conditions under which an UMP test does not exist?

**EDIT**: I have found an example in which, instead, although the alternative hypothesis is bilateral, the UMP test exists.

A sample $X\sim U(0,\theta)$. The hypotheses are $H_0:\theta=\theta_0, H_1:\theta\neq \theta_0$.

[image: Lehman, 1986 p.111]

Comment: Simply put, a UMP test does not exist because the critical regions turn out to be different for $\theta> \theta_0$ and $\theta<\theta_0$. This means that there are only UMP tests for one-sided hypotheses, where you may still use the NP lemma.

Comment: @JohnK Ok, that's clear. But how can I apply this idea to the two examples above? How can I show that it is actually the case?

Comment: I am not familiar with a general proof. Perhaps you can work something out starting from the definition of an exponential density. My guess is that it would be non-trivial.

Comment: @JohnK Thus, in your opinion, it is enough to take those cases as given? Are there other cases in which we are sure a UMP test does not exist?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177728259

Comment: @fcop Which part in particular? Reading the abstract it seems not so pertinent

Comment: @Alessandro: you don't have to read it, but maybe you can Google 'Karlin rubin uniform power monotone likelihood' and then judge whether it is pertinent or not...

Comment: @fcop Ok thanks. Since you've linked a paper, I thought I was supposed to read through it

Comment: @Alessandro: it depends on how deep you want to dive into it. I think the paper is interesting to learn which conditions are needed and why

Comment: After your edit: you say that an UMPT exists, that could be but , what is your test statistic, what is the critical region ?

Comment: @Alessandro: I am not giving an idea but I am asking you a question: you say that an UMP test exists for your hypothesis and I ask you (a) what is the test statistic and (b) what is your critical region ? If you say that there exists an UMPT test, then you should be able to give me the test statistic and the critical region ?

Comment: @fcop I've uploaded the source of my example. It is Lehmann, 1986 p. 111. It is an exercise, so I do not have already the answers to your questions

Comment: I thought you were interested in exponential densities. The uniform distribution does not belong to the exponential family so there is no general rule there.

Comment: @JohnK Sorry for the delay. I was interested in general to situations in which an UMP test exists and in those in which, instead, it does not exist. 
So, in the case of exponential family and simple vs bilateral hypothesis, the UMP test does not exist as a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that you have provided, go on to calculate the likelihood ratio and you will find that it comes out to be a function of the order statistics, X(1) and X(2). Question 8.33 of Statistical Inference by George and Casella will help. The solution is provided in the link below:
http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams570/Solutions-Casella-Berger.pdf

Coming back to the existence of a UMP test, Karlin Rubin Theorem tells that the MLR should exist, so that the inverse operation can be applied to get the test. The example on the link below will surely help.
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cscott/past_courses/eecs564w11/25_ump.pdf